# ng-http-loader keeps on loading in angular electron app

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, ipc, electron-builder

I am sending an event from my electron main process to angular using IPC communication as below:

//in main.js

```
win.webContents.send('info');
```

//in angular file which is listening to this event

```
this.electronService.ipcRenderer.on('info', () => {
  // calling a function here which is performing a HTTP request
})
```

I am using **ng-http-loader** to show a loader whenever a HTTP request is made.

The problem I am facing is that the loader keeps alive (keeps on loading) here.
I am not able to understand this behavior that why this is happening because it is working fine everywhere else.

The problem is coming only when I am sending the event from electron to angular. Can anybody help?

Comment: Perhaps you can create and interceptor that manually hides the loader after a response is received. `.finally(()=> this.loaderService.hide())` add this to a httpInterceptor.